# How do I change fill_alpha of a Bokeh chart based on data

Tags: python, bokeh

I have plotted a Bokeh rectangle chart. I want the fill_alpha to be high for 1 row and low for rest of all. I there a way I can modify fill_alpha based on input data?

I tried using color mappers  as in fill colors but it didn't work.

```py
mapper = LinearColorMapper(palette=RdBu, low=-1, high=1)
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['AllColumns1']=["A","B","C", "D"]
df['AllColumns2']=["A","B","C", "D"]
df['value']=[0.1, 0.4, 0.9, -0.3]
p = figure(title='Title', x_range = list(df.AllColumns1), y_range - list(df.Allcolumns2)
r = p.rect(x='AllColumns1', y='AllColumns2', height = 1, width=1, source = ColumnDataSource(df),fill_alpha = 0.5, fill_color =transform('value', mapper))
show(p)
```

I want the row where value is "A" to have fill_alpha = 1 and rest 0.5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are various ways to do this. The simplest most, direct method is just to make a column with the alpha values you want, yourself e.g.:

```
df['alpha'] = [1, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5]
```

Then configure your `rect` to use it:

```
p.rect(..., alpha='alpha', source=df)
```

Similarly, for colors.

If you really want to map things only in the browser, then you could use a `CustomJSTransform` for the alpha, and a `LinearColorMapper` for the RGB color values (color mappers do not map alphas). You can see an example of using a color mapper with rects [here](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/master/examples/plotting/file/unemployment.py).